# High performance array mean

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I've got a performance bottleneck. I'm computing the column-wise mean of large arrays (250 rows & 1.3 million columns), and I do so more than a million times in my application.

My test case in Python:

```
import numpy as np
big_array = np.random.random((250, 1300000))
%timeit mean = big_array.mean(axis = 0) # ~400 milliseconds
```

Numpy takes around 400 milliseconds on my machine, running on a single core. I've tried several other matrix libraries across different languages (Cython, R, Julia, Torch), but found only Julia to beat Numpy, by taking around 250 milliseconds.

Can anyone provide evidence of substantial improvements in performance in this task? Perhaps this is a task suited for the GPU?

Edit: My application is evidently memory-constrained, and its performance is dramatically improved by accessing elements of a large array only once, rather than repeatedly. (See comment below.)

Comment: This computation is probably more about memory access than about CPU work.  I wouldn't expect any system to significantly improve upon numpy here.  My intuition is that using multiple core or a GPU would not be of much use.  Reducing down to float32 might help though.

Comment: Test case may have been too simple. My array type is actually going to be boolean, so every element is stored as a byte with Numpy. Paradoxically, it takes longer to get mean or sum for a boolean array than for floats as in example. Any idea how to perform operation on bitpacked array, which would reduce memory traffic by ~90%?

Comment: In my particular application, I take the mean of arrays which are 250-row subsets of a 22,000-row array. Memory accesses alone total to 24+ hours for the whole computation. If I operate on larger matrix, however, and touch each element only once, memory accesses total to fewer than 10 seconds. I'll have to try that! Thanks @MRocklin for pointing out the bottleneck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Julia, if I'm not mistaken, uses fortran ordering in memory as opposed to numpy which uses C memory layout by default. So if you rearrange things to adhere to the same layout so that the mean is happening along contiguous memory, you get better performance:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: big_array = np.random.random((250, 1300000))

In [4]: big_array_f = np.asfortranarray(big_array)

In [5]: %timeit mean = big_array.mean(axis = 0)
1 loop, best of 3: 319 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit mean = big_array_f.mean(axis = 0)
1 loop, best of 3: 205 ms per loop
```

Or you can just change you dimensions and take the mean over the other axis:

```
In [10]: big_array = np.random.random((1300000, 250))

In [11]: %timeit mean = big_array.mean(axis = 1)
1 loop, best of 3: 205 ms per loop
```

Comment: On my computer, the timing is reversed : 
In [56]: %timeit big_array.mean(0)   ->  705 ms per loop ;
In [57]: %timeit big_arrayf.mean(0)  -> 1201 ms per loop ;
Have you any idea ?